# White space query issue in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

```
GET taps/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        { "match": { "test_card": "ZE-S-180x4" }},
        { "match": { "pf": "ZX480" }},
        { "match": { "fpc": "AEZE 3D MP+6E" }},
        { "match": { "rpd": "32" }},
        { "match": { "rel": "25" }},
        { "match": { "rel_type": "1234_daily" }}
      ]
    }
}
}
```

fpc is not getting as single word match, it's querying as 3 words and getting more results.

Answer (score 1):

In order for ES to ignore spaces, what if you have the plus signs between the string values in the below `match`:

```
{ "match": { "fpc": "AEZE","3D","MP+6E" }}
```

**OR**

when you're creating the mapping for the fields, you can have the fields which you need to match exactly as below:

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/my_index -d '{
   "mappings": {
       "my_type": {
           "properties": {
               "instruments": {
                   "type": "string",
                   "index": "not_analyzed" <--- you need to have this for the field to get tokenized
               }
           }
       }
   }
}'
```

Then of course you could go on match the string with white spaces.

[Ref](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/search-query-issue-using-term-and-spaces/3186/7) & this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23150670/elasticsearch-match-vs-term-query?rq=1) could be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The value in database will be with spaces
 "AEZE 3D MP+6E"only. So can i get right results.

Comment: Did you try checking your result by changing your fpc match to either one of the above in the answer?

Comment: Sorry, Our server is down as of now. So asking before it comes up. I will run and get back to you. If you have idea please get back.

Comment: @venkat any effects after the changes ?

Comment: No, It is throwing syntax error. 
{ "match": { "fpc_type":  "MPC5E"+"3D"+"24XGE+6XLGE" }},
Error below
"reason": "Unexpected character ('+' (code 43)): was expecting comma to separate Object entries\n at [Source: [B@1c6dfecf; line: 5, column: 43]"

I am running command in sense

Comment: @venkat what if you remove the + and insert a comma `,` instead of + ? I've updated the answer.