# Term Query does not work where match query works

Tags: elasticsearch

In my index i have a document indexed with the field named "sn" with the value "Dorsett Shepherds Bush". When I use the match query, I can retrieve the document, but with term query I cannot retrieve the document. **"sn" is a keyword field**. I am doing a exact match, but still cannot get the results with the term query.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank You.

Comment: Could you provide some sample code?

Comment: You should show your mapping and the query you're running.

Comment: Following is the mapping for the field. 

"sn": {
           "type": "keyword",
           "include_in_all": false
}

Comment: Update your question with the mapping you get when running `curl -XGET localhost:9200/your_index`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [elasticsearch match vs term query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23150670/elasticsearch-match-vs-term-query)