# Elastic Search - query not matching

Tags: elasticsearch-5

My index was created in C#:

```
CreateIndexRequest request = new CreateIndexRequest(index.ToString().ToLower());
TypeMapping typeMapping = new TypeMapping();
typeMapping.DateDetection = false;
request.Mappings = new Mappings();
request.Mappings.Add("object", typeMapping);
esConfig.CreateIndex(request);
```

Here's the after the fact definition of a field i'm trying to query called 'traceText":

```
      "traceText": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      },
```

When I do this search, I'm not getting any hits:

```
GET /local-tlrgloadtenderout-2018.06.04/_search
{"query": {
     "term" : {"traceText":"Global-Catch-Error"}
}}
```

similar with something simpler on a similar field:

```
GET /local-tlrgloadtenderout-2018.06.04/_search
{"query": {
     "term" : {"traceLevel":"E"}
}}
```

When I use Kibana, I can specify:

```
  traceText:'Global-Catch-Error'
```

or

```
  traceLevel: 'E'
```

and everything works perfectly.

What do I need to do to get the Elastic Search query to work?  I'm using Version 6.0.0.

Answer (score 0):

I tried changing "term" to "match" and it worked.  See explanation in this StackOverflow question: [elasticsearch match vs term query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23150670/elasticsearch-match-vs-term-query)