# Elasticsearch query do not work with @ value

Tags: elasticsearch

When I execute a simple search query on an email it does not return anything to me, unless I remove what follows the "@", why?

I wish to make queries on the e-mails in fuzzy and autocompletion.

**ELASTICSEARCH INFOS:**

```
{
  "name" : "ZZZ",
  "cluster_name" : "YYY",
  "cluster_uuid" : "XXX",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "6.5.2",
    "build_flavor" : "default",
    "build_type" : "tar",
    "build_hash" : "WWW",
    "build_date" : "2018-11-29T23:58:20.891072Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "7.5.0",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "5.6.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "5.0.0"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

**MAPPING :**

```
PUT users
{
  "mappings":
  {
    "_doc": { "properties": { "mail": { "type": "text" } } }
  }
}
```

**ALL DATAS :**

```
[
    { "mail": "firstname.lastname@company.com" },
    { "mail": "john.doe@company.com" }
]
```

**QUERY WORKS :**

Term request works but `mail == "firstname.lastname@company.com"` and not "firstname.lastname"...

```
QUERY :
GET users/_search
{ "query": { "term": { "mail": "firstname.lastname" } }}

RETURN :
{
  "took": 7,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": { "total": 6, "successful": 6, "skipped": 0, "failed": 0 },
  "hits": {
    "total": 1,
    "max_score": 4.336203,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "users",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "H1dQ4WgBypYasGfnnXXI",
        "_score": 4.336203,
        "_source": {
          "mail": "firstname.lastname@company.com"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**QUERY NOT WORKS :**

```
QUERY :
GET users/_search
{ "query": { "term": { "mail": "firstname.lastname@company.com" } }}

RETURN :
{
  "took": 0,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": { "total": 6, "successful": 6, "skipped": 0, "failed": 0 },
  "hits": {
    "total": 0,
    "max_score": null,
    "hits": []
  }
}
```

---

**SOLUTION :**

Change mapping (reindex after mapping changes) with `uax_url_email` analyzer for mails.

```
PUT users
{
  "settings":
  {
    "index": { "analysis": { "analyzer": { "mail": { "tokenizer":"uax_url_email" } } } }
  }
  "mappings":
  {
    "_doc": { "properties": { "mail": { "type": "text", "analyzer":"mail" } } }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use no other tokenizer for your indexed text field, it will use the standard tokenizer, which tokenizes on the @ symbol [I don't have a source on this, but there's proof below].

If you use a term query rather than a match query then that exact term will be searched for in the inverted index [elasticsearch match vs term query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23150670/elasticsearch-match-vs-term-query).

Your inverted index looks like this

```
GET users/_analyze
{
  "text": "firstname.lastname@company.com"
}

{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "firstname.lastname",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 18,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 0
    },
    {
      "token": "company.com",
      "start_offset": 19,
      "end_offset": 30,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

To resolve this you could specify your own analyzer for the mail field *or* you could use the match query, which will analyze your searched text just like how it analyzes the indexed text.

```
GET users/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "mail": "firstname.lastname@company.com"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I can not use match because the mail must be exactly the same, but I will look for more information about tokenizer. thank you very much.

Comment: You've probably figured it out already but the uax_url_email tokenizer might be what you want https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-uaxurlemail-tokenizer.html

Comment: Yes it is, I will add the solution to my post, thank you again