# Elastic Search full string match not working

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

I am using Elastic builder npm

Using `esb.termQuery(Email, "test")`

Mapping:

```
"CompanyName": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Database fields:

```
"Email": "test@mycompany.com",
"CompanyName": "my company"
```

Query JSON: `{ term: { CompanyName: 'my' } }`. or `{ term: { Email: 'test' } }`
Result :

```
"Email": "test@mycompany.com",
    "CompanyName": "my company"
```

Expectation:
No result, need a full-text match, Match here is acting like 'like' or queryStringQuery.

I have 3 filters prefix, exact match, include.

Comment: did you get a chance to go through my answer, looking forward to get feedback from you  If my answer helped you resolve your issue, then please don't forget to upvote and accept my answer 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The [standard analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html) is the default analyzer which is used if none is
> specified. It provides grammar based tokenization

**In your example, maybe that you are not specifying any analyzer explicitly in the index mapping, therefore text fields are analyzed by default and the standard analyzer is the default analyzer for them.
Refer this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56800073/disabling-elasticsearch-search-analyzer), to get a detailed explanation on this.**

The following tokens are generated if no analyzer is defined.

```
POST/_analyze 

{
  "analyzer" : "standard",
  "text" : "test@mycompany.com"
}
```

Tokens are:

```
{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "test",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 4,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 0
    },
    {
      "token": "mycompany.com",
      "start_offset": 5,
      "end_offset": 18,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

**If you want a full-text search then you can define a custom analyzer with a lowercase filter, lowercase filter will ensure that all the letters are changed to lowercase before indexing the document and searching.**

> The [normalizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/normalizer.html) property of keyword fields is similar to analyzer
> except that it guarantees that the analysis chain produces a single
> token.
>
> The [uax_url_email](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-uaxurlemail-tokenizer.html) tokenizer is like the standard tokenizer except that
> it recognises URLs and email addresses as single tokens.

**Index Mapping:**

```
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "normalizer": {
        "my_normalizer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase"
          ]
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "my_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "my_tokenizer"
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "my_tokenizer": {
          "type": "uax_url_email"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "CompanyName": {
        "type": "keyword",
        "normalizer": "my_normalizer"
      },
      "Email": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Index Data:**

```
{
  "Email": "test@mycompany.com",
  "CompanyName": "my company"
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "CompanyName": "My Company"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "Email": "test"
          }
        }
      ],
      "minimum_should_match": 1
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "stof_64220291",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0.2876821,
        "_source": {
          "Email": "test@mycompany.com",
          "CompanyName": "my company"
        }
      }
    ]
```

Comment: using keyword facing issues with capital letters in CompanyName.

Comment: "CompanyName": "My Company"

Comment: @Amit Rana do you want to make a match on capital letter i.e. `My Company` also ?

Comment: Fron frontend I can get capital and small both. I am converting to lowercase then using the term I am searching on Elastic. If I use keyword then no result with lowercase

Comment: @Amit Rana okay, and what are the conditions on email, do you want that it should not split ?

Comment: I can check if a special character exists then I can use .keyword. Will that be a good solution?

Comment: I want a simple full string match on all fields, Frontend can send any field with full string match.

Comment: @AmitRana for email you can use `uax_url_email tokenizer`, it recognises URLs and email addresses as single tokens. Please go through my updated answer, and let me know if this was your issue ?

Comment: @AmitRana have added `uax_url_email tokenizer`, in the index mapping as well. Please go through my answer, and let me know if this was your issue :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, User can insert new custom fields, and I am inserting them to elastic, When I need to insert normalized for those fields?

Comment: @AmitRana sorry I forgot to update my search query according to the normalized field (mentioned in the mapping before). But now I have changed my index mapping, and you will be able to use the same search query (to get your search results). Reg your above question, you can add `"normalizer": "my_normalizer"`, in the index mapping definition of that particular field (where you want to implement case insensitive use case)